# Angular 2 round down

Tags: angular2-template

```
{{(countValue/60) %60 | number:'2.0-0'}}
```

is there is a way to round down, the above code will give the result for "0.9" is "1" I want 0 can anyone help me

Comment: u dont need any fraction at all? only wanted to round down to the nearest digit? then you can use 'Math.floor(yourNumber)' function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this either you can just use

```
Math.floor(yourValue);
```

or if you wanted to use custom pipes., pls refer the code below

```
// round.pipe.ts
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({name: 'round'})
export class RoundPipe implements PipeTransform {
    /**
     *
     * @param value
     * @returns {number}
     */
    transform(value: number): number {
        return Math.floor(value);
    }
}
```

Import it in your module

```
// app.module.ts
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        routing
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        RoundPipe
    ],
    providers: [
        BaseRequestOptions
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

And in your html,

```
<!--your html -->
<span>{{(countValue/60) %60 | round }}</span>
```